# Arduino Uno DS1302 RTC module not incrementing time

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to create an alarm clock using my DS1302 RTC and Liquid Crystal Display, however I have run into a problem. When reading the time from the RTC it stays on the time I originally set it to, not moving at all.

I have tried using different libraries and also tried using both digital pinouts and I2C pinouts, but nothing has worked; they all never increment time.

```cpp
LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);
DS1302 rtc(10, 11, 13);

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  rtc.halt(false);
  rtc.writeProtect(false);

  rtc.setTime(12, 0, 0);
}

void loop()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Time: ");
  lcd.print(rtc.getTimeStr());
  delay(1000);
}
```

The time should increment as I have seen in multiple videos on youtube using similar code, but the time always stays as 12 o'clock even when commenting out the line that sets it.

Comment: Post a link to DS1302 library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is a wrong tag "rational-team-concert" added to this question, I guess it should be something "real-time-counter" or similar.

Usually a question with appropriate tags gets the questions cleared faster.